# snakemake one to many with checkpoints

Tags: snakemake

I am building a Snakemake pipeline and I have a rule that creates a folder and fills it with *n* files. I then want to run the next rule (checkpoint) on each of the *n* files, and aggregate the output.

Currently my issue is defining the input for the checkpoint rule. The previous rule outputs a directory, and the files in this directory have a constant naming structure `range(n).fa` (where range(n) signifies 0:(n-1)). I have been having trouble getting the checkpoint to accept these files as input.

Here is my current structure:

```
...

rule make_ORF_dir:
    input:
       "snake_test/Storage/ORFs.csv"
    output:
        region_split = directory("snake_test/Storage/split_ORFs/")
    params:
        chnks="snake_test/Storage/split_ORFs/{chunk}.fa"
    conda:
        "../enviroment.yml"
    shell:
        "python workflow/scripts/Split_ORFs.py --ORF_csv {input} --out_dir {output} --num_splits 1000"



checkpoint find_novel:
    input:
        expand("snake_test/Storage/split_ORFs/{chunk}.fa", chunk = range(1000))
    output:
        directory("snake_test/Results/{chunk}")
    conda:
        "../enviroment.yml"
    shell:
        "python scripts/CLI.py --sequences {input} --db_file ../Data/ref.fa --result_dir {output}"


...
```

This results in the error:

```
Missing input files for rule find_novel:
    output: snake_test/Results
    affected files:
        snake_test/Storage/split_ORFs/848.fa
        snake_test/Storage/split_ORFs/278.fa
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of checkpoint:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "final.txt"

rule first:
    output:
        touch("text.txt")

checkpoint randomFiles:
    input:
        rules.first.output[0]
    output:
        newDir=directory("newContent")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output}
        randomNumbers=$(seq 1 15 | shuf -n 1)
        for i in $(seq 1 $randomNumbers)
        do
            echo $i > {output}/$RANDOM.txt
        done
        """

rule intermediate:
    input:
        "newContent/{i}.txt"
    output:
        "process/{i}.txt"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.randomFiles.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("process/{i}.txt",
           i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, "{i}.txt")).i)

rule aggregate:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        "final.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```